# Scraping data from drop down List generated with javascript

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

In this link : "https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do", How can i retrieve data from the "Foro" drop down list using requests or another library.

Anyone could shed a light ?

Comment: The data in the list is already in an accessible variable on the page: $.saj.cpopg.locaisDePesquisa - you can grab the data from there directly

Comment: The idea is to achieve that in python with requests, but at this moment i don't know how to do that. If you can provide code solution, i will be grateful

Comment: Sorry I dont know python. But generally heres a quick grab of the data:
https://repl.it/repls/BigheartedLumpySpreadsheets

And a decent guide to it:
https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f

Comment: Thank you so much @AaronGibson, you help a lot

Comment: .....Even if you use beautiful soup,you couldn't get the data in the "Foro" dropmenu from html directly.Because this value is in the `Javascript`.

Comment: You can get it but it would be a case of using regex or something to get the value and then parse it.